# Cant get .click to open in a new tab

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a javascript macro to open a specific link on a site in a new tab, but I'm not able to get the link to open in a new tab.

Here's the code:

```
document.onload = window.frames[0].document.getElementsByClassName('TextCell SA Link FW100 AL')[0].click()
```

I've tried using the `window.open()` function, but it doesn't seem to be working for me. Here's how I wrote it

```
document.onload=window.open(window.frames[0].document.getElementsByClassName('TextCell SA Link FW100 AL')[0].click(),'_blank')
```

HTML:

```
<td class="TextCell SA Link FW100 AL" 
    onclick="(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); e.stopPropagation(); return autotask.siteNavigation.__openPage(new Autotask.PopupPage('ProjectDetail','\/projects\/views\/100\/prjView_100.asp',false,'objectID','2359',false,false,new Autotask.PopupSettings(550,null,950,null,false))); })(event)">
    P20190930.0003
</td>
```

Comment: Instead of trying to simulate a click event, just grab the `href` attribute value and popup a new window / tab with it

Comment: There is no `href` attribute on the page. Here's the element in html `<td class="TextCell SA Link FW100 AL" onclick="(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); e.stopPropagation(); return autotask.siteNavigation.__openPage(new Autotask.PopupPage('ProjectDetail','\/projects\/views\/100\/prjView_100.asp',false,'objectID','2359',false,false,new Autotask.PopupSettings(550,null,950,null,false))); })(event)">P20190930.0003</td>`

Comment: show the html code

Answer (score 0):

Syntax of [`window.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) is

> var *window* = window.open(url, windowName, [windowFeatures]);

Here, as you are trying to grab the click event of the td, `window.open` wont work

Try this.

```
// document.addEventListener('load', (event) =>
document.onload = (event) => {
  // var tdList = window.frames[0].document.getElementsByClassName('TextCell SA Link FW100 AL');
  var tdList = window.frames[0].document.querySelectorAll('.TextCell.SA.Link.FW100.AL');
  if(tdList && tdList.length) {
    tdList[0].click();
  } else {
    alert('TD not found.');
  }
};
```

Please note that it

Comment: Gave this a shot, but it's not clicking the link or displaying an alert

Comment: So, the `HTML ELement` is *found*. You should alert (tdList[0].inner.HTML) and see if its the same element we are checking. There will be multiple tds within multiple trs

Comment: I cant even get that to work. Here's the code im using `document.onload = (event) => {
  // var tdList = window.frames[0].document.getElementsByClassName('TextCell SA Link FW100 AL');
  var tdList = window.frames[0].document.querySelectorAll('.TextCell.SA.Link.FW100.AL');
  if(tdList && tdList.length) {
    alert(tdList[0].innerHTML);
  } else {
    alert('TD not found.');
  }
};
`

Comment: I took out the `document.onload = (event)` and just ran the `var tdList = window.frames[0].document.querySelectorAll('.TextCell.SA.Link.FW100.AL');alert(tdlist[0].innerHTML) ` and the alert showed the correct link

Comment: if I remove the `document.onload = (event) =>` it does, but it still opens in a new window

Comment: window.open always opens a new window. AFAIK, I dont know of a way to make it always open in a new tab https://stackoverflow.com/q/4907843/17447